# How can I know a db lib support the asynchronous call?

Tags: python, database, asynchronous

Today, I downloaded a scrapy project from GitHub. I found a piece of a comment in the `MogoPipeline` (a class used to save data to mongodb). It says:

> The only async framework that PyMongo fully supports is Gevent.
>                Currently there is no great way to use PyMongo in conjunction with Tornado or Twisted. PyMongo provides built-in
>   connection pooling, so some of the benefits of those frameworks can be
>   achieved just by writing multi-threaded code that shares a
>   MongoClient.

Maybe this project is a little old. I see a lib named `asyncmongo` in GitHub.
What I want to ask is why a db lib is not native compatible to asynchronous calls? I am sorry I have never used a async framework in past. I use MySQL-python, redis-py and sqlalchemy in some of my projects. Do they support async?

How can I know a lib support async if it does not announce it in doc? What should I pay attention to use a db lib in an async framework?

Comment: db driver won't by asynchronous by accident (I/O is blocking (synchronous) by default in Python). Moreover, the implementation is most probably framework-specific (twisted, tornado, gevent). `scrapy` implies that you need twisted-based library.